# Basemap widget to access map layers from ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Can a basemap widget retrieve a list of map layers from an ArcGIS server instead of ArcGIS Online or Portal? If not, how can I get or build a similar widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you [create a new Basemap Gallery](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/basemapgallery-amd.html#basemapgallery1), one of the properties is `basemaps`, which is "An array of user-defined basemaps to display in the BasemapGallery".

See the example code in the documentation [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/basemapgallery-amd.html#basemapgallery1).